# How to get string from stdin with escape sequence?

Tags: c

A simple code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello\tworld");
    char line[1000];
    gets(line);
    printf("%s\n",line);
    return 0;
}
```

So if I typed in "Hello\tworld" it will print out "Hello\tworld", but a pre-defined string "Hello\tworld" will be printed out as:

```
hello       world
```

Is there any way to make the gets function be aware of escape sequences?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you type in "Hello World"?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting what you type when you type "\t" in stdin it is stored as `'\'` and `'t'`  and not ascii equivalent of `'\t'` .Why don't you use "tab-key" for `\t` in stdin ?

Answer (score 1):

The string on printf("Hello\tworld"); **it's converted by the compiler** to a compiled string where escape codes are converted to characters, so the printf function when executed does not see a two char "\t" string but the equivalent code for a single tabulation character. But the gets() function gets the string of every typed character **at runtime** and does not convert escape codes. So if you want to convert those escape codes yo have to make a replace function.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  You will need to manually replace the occurrances of escaped character sequences to their corresponding characters

Answer (score 0):

The gets function doesn't look at any symbols (ex: \t \n), just gives the ascii of each char entered. As far as I know, there is not way to have it pay attention to such, other than manually replacing the ones you care about. scanf is the same way and will give you the same problem.